# Why are decimal numbers immune to rounding errors?

Tags: .net, floating-point, decimal

I do not understand why decimals can represent numbers like 0.1 and floating points cannot.  I have read so many articles and questions on this e.g. this one: [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

The answerer in the link above states that floating points are base 2 and decimals are base 10.  I believe this has something to do with it.  However, I have the same confusion as @BKSpurgeon  (comment under the answer).  Everything is base 2 in the end?

Comment: They're not immune to rounding errors - they can just represent base10 numbers precisely. See if http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx and http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx help... but if not, it would be worth editing the question to be clearer about what you're looking for... or just add a comment to the answer on the other question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks.  I read your article at the weekend and it helped.  However, I cannot get my head around the base 2 v base 10 argument.  Everything is base 2 in the end isn't it? I plan to buy your book (C# in depth) in the next few days as I will have to use C# more in future.

Comment: Well, there are certainly "bits"... but for both binary floating point and decimal floating point, you can think of the number as being an integer and a scale... and in decimal, that "integer" is treated as being base 10, so an integer of 123 and a scale of -2 would end up as 1.23.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, could you provide an example of a number that has rounding errors when represented as floating point, but does not have rounding errors as a decimal?

Comment: Sure: 0.1. That can't be exactly represented in binary, but is represented as "1, scaled by shifting one digit to the right" in decimal. (Note that decimal is still "floating point" - it's just that it's *decimal* floating point rather than *binary* floating point.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Ah, it is the arithmetic that is base 10 (in the case of a decimal) instead of the storage (which is always base 2).  Is that correct?

Comment: Well, sort of. I don't think I'd express it that way, but it's the base in which you interpret the number when shifting...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, how would you express it? I realise this question is quite old but thought I would ask.  I have never got my head around this properly.  I now have a requirement, which may need a Floating Point number (never used them before).

Comment: I'd say that the storage is as an integer, scaled by some power of ten... so you could write it as a *decimal* integer and then shift the decimal point... that would be an accurate representation of what's stored.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal numbers do indeed appear to be *error free* from rounding so long as you write them out with a radix of 10. They most certainly are **not** "base 2 in the end".

IEEE754 floating point numbers are also *error free* from rounding if you write them out with a radix of 2.